# iOS 8 (.0 to .3) vs 8.4 Share Extension

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

While developing with all my tools up to date, I noticed that on 8.3 and lower devices my extension seems to have disappeared and not show at all in the list from which users can enable it. I extracted the contents of the app file and the extension does get compiled and packaged.

On a few devices we decided to update, the extension immediately started showing up on iOS 8.4 devices (post update with no app reinstall required).

What's up with this? Has anyone else run into this issue? Is there anything I can do to fix it?

NB: I have to mention, the only thing that changed was updating our dev tools. The extension project was untouched. Dev environment is using Xamarin.

Comment: Check that the target iOS version is not 8.4

Comment: My deployment target is set to 8.0, like I've said, since 8.4 it just doesn't show even though it's clearly packaged and it used to work on my test devices and no changes have been made to the project. I've even meticulously inspected every single file in the project including the project file and solution file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking with Xamarin, the project template does not set the deployment target in the info.plist by default (or it might have gotten lost with updates to the tooling).

If the "Deployment Target" is not set, the extension will only show on devices running the latest os version that was supported at the time the app was packaged.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the CFBundleDisplayName and CFBundleName values are both set in your Info.plist for the Share Extension. If my memory serves correctly, I've run into the same issue before and that's how I managed solved it.

Comment: They are both already set. Like I said, the extension used to work just fine on all 8.0+ devices before apple introduced 8.4, after 8.4 was released and xcode & xamarin updated, the extension does not show up on any devices unless they update to 8.4